# Chrome remote debug display issue

Tags: google-chrome, web, mobile, browser, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug remote Chrome, the device could be connected, and inspect the tab starts fine.

But in the window of remote debug, everything is a mess. the GUI is terrible, which makes the functionality totally unusable, see picture below:

[image]

1. resize this window or change the resolution is not working.
2. some times tabs like elements, source, networks could presents, but under the source tab, there is  search bar keep presents and covers all area of the codes area.
3. this is totally not working.

OS: Win7.
PC Chrome version: 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I don't think this should related to Mobile Chrome or android version.

Is there any possible reason for this?
I think Chrome is a widely using browser this can't be a formal released bug for Chrome, right?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this. Mine has been this way for months. Was working fine. Need this

Comment: i have the same issue even on 69.0.3497.100